# Add a column that does a calculation based on how it matches two other columns

Tags: python, pandas, calculated-columns

I want to compare two columns and then calculate a weighted average of the values based on the comparison.

Here, we see that Code is the same and ID varies, but repeats. I want Value_new to be a column that shows the weighted multiple of Value. For example, ID = 1 repeats 4 times. Value_new for the first row will therefore be `0.5/(0.5+0.5+0.7+1) = 0.185`

Have:

```
Code    ID  Value
66099   1   0.3
55933   1   0.5
55933   2   0.4
55933   1   0.5
55933   1   0.7
55933   1   1
55933   2   2
55933   2   0.8
55933   3   3
55933   4   6
55933   5   7
```

Want (1st row = `0.5/(0.5+0.5+0.7+1) = 0.185`:

```
Code    ID  Value   Value_new
66099   1   0.3 0.3
55933   1   0.5 0.185185185
55933   2   0.4 0.125
55933   1   0.5 0.185185185
55933   1   0.7 0.259259259
55933   1   1   0.37037037
55933   2   2   0.625
55933   2   0.8 0.25
55933   3   3   1
55933   4   6   1.5
55933   5   7   1.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are getting the values for the categories with only one value (for instance, why is the first row's `Value_new` set to `0.3`, and why are the last 2 rows `1.5` and `1.4`?), but IIUC based on your description of your desired output, this works using `transform`:

```
df['Value_new'] = df.groupby(['Code','ID'])['Value'].transform(lambda x: x/x.sum())

>>> df
     Code  ID  Value  Value_new
0   66099   1    0.3   1.000000
1   55933   1    0.5   0.185185
2   55933   2    0.4   0.125000
3   55933   1    0.5   0.185185
4   55933   1    0.7   0.259259
5   55933   1    1.0   0.370370
6   55933   2    2.0   0.625000
7   55933   2    0.8   0.250000
8   55933   3    3.0   1.000000
9   55933   4    6.0   1.000000
10  55933   5    7.0   1.000000
```

Comment: Think this is more efficient... `df['Value'] / df.groupby(['Code', 'ID'])['Value'].transform('sum')`.

Comment: What does the `lambda x: x/x.sum())` part do?

Comment: It's an anonymous function that takes the `Value` and divides it by the sum of `Value`s for that group